# What conditions cause object instantiation to return null?

Tags: java, constructor, null, return-value, new-operator

Is it possible for the following line to return null?

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

If so, what conditions would cause a return value of null?

Comment: I'm intrigured as to what prompted this question.

Comment: @KevinD It sounds like a Java certification exam question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's impossible for `new` to return null, assuming the VM is functioning correctly.

From [section 15.9.4 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.9.4):

> The value of a class instance creation expression is a reference to the newly created object of the specified class. Every time the expression is evaluated, a fresh object is created.

Answer (score 6):

No, this can't return null. It could, however, throw an exception and depending on how you handle that exception the `obj` reference might still be null after the exception is handled (if you leave the code block, e.g. by not catching the exception, the `obj` reference would cease to exist and thus it wouldn't matter).

Reasons for exceptions in a constructor are manifold, for example if you run out of memory (in which case you get an `OutOfMemoryError`) or if you access an uninitialized field which is still null and would cause a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 4):

a static initializer error

like

```
public class MyClass {

static {
  throw new Error("Error");
}

}

public class MyClass2 {

  static MyClass test=new MyClass();

}
```

You cannot ask your question without specifying the context. In an application server, the above will creare Myclass2 with test=null.
Why ? Because the Error is typically trapped by the application server.

Comment: can you expand the answer with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - NO.

But you can throw an exception from a constructor, in which case, if `obj` was initially assigned to `null`, it will remain `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is impossible. If somehow you run out of memory in Java you will get [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) exception.