# SecureRandom class in Android giving null in some cases

Tags: android, cryptography, nonce, secure-random

I am using SecureRandom class in android to generate cryptographically secure random value of 64 bytes. But in our logging tool we have observed null values getting generated in random cases without any pattern. Any one knows why it is happening.

Below is code snippet

```
 public static byte[] generateNonce() {
        byte[] nonce = new byte[64];
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        secureRandom.nextBytes(nonce);
        return nonce;
    }
```

Comment: There are two references created in your method, `nonce` and `secureRandom`. Which one is set to null? In any event it is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183946/238704) for a normal functioning VM to return null in either case, so there must be VM problem, or you have misdiagnosed what is occurring.

Comment: I get this issue sometimes, difficult to reproduce. Any updates?